# Want to programmatically add git for "media files" to track their history from views.py

Tags: python, django, git

I want to add git to media files stored by django in the media folder I looked at different modules of python to track the media files (gitpython, sh) but all of them give error "Permission denied". I think it is some environment problem. Help would be appreciated

```py
def simple_upload(request):
    username = None
    if request.method == "POST" and request.FILES["myfile"]:
        myfile = request.FILES["myfile"]

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            username = request.user.username
            user_dir = "/media/" + username
            fs = FileSystemStorage(location="media")
            fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
            if not is_git_repo(user_dir):
                sh.git.init(user_dir)

            rep = sh.git.bake(_cwd=user_dir)
            rep.init()
            rep.add(user_dir + "/" + myfile.name)
            rep.commit(m="hmmm")
            t = rep.head.commit.tree
            print(rep.git.diff(t))
        return render(request, "simple_upload.html", {"uploaded_file_url": ""})
    return render(request, "simple_upload.html")
```